# Include C Library in iOS project

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I am working on a project in iOS using Xcode. I want to include a library written in C. But I don't know how to use C library in Objective-C. 
Here is the link of Library: https://github.com/bcl/aisparser

Can someone help me?

Comment: Another option is to make your Objective-C files Objective-C++ files by changing their extension to .mm and then you can mix your C++ and Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to hit one obstacle in the form of what's called "name mangling". C++ stores function names in a way not compatible with Obj-C.

Objective-C doesn't implement classes in the same way as C++, so it's not going to like it.

One way around this is to implement a set of simple C functions which call the C++ functions. It'll be a good challenge to keep the number of C functions as low as possible! You'll end up with a nice compact interface! :)

To declare these functions in a C++ file, you'll need to mark them as C with:

```
 extern "C" int function_name(char *blob,int number, double foo) {...}
```

This disables the standard name-mangling.

Build a header file with the prototypes for all these functions that you can share with your objective C code.

You won't be able to pass classes around in the same way (because your ObjC code can't use them), but you'll be able to pass pointers (although you might have to lie about the types a little).